# $-4a^3-27b^2$ is a square in $F_{p^n}$ .

Tags: galois-theory

*question*: Let $a,b \in F_{p^n}$ if $x^3+ax+b$ is irreducible then $-4a^3-27b^2$ is a square in $F_{p^n}$ .

*answer*:

as $f$ is a irreducible polynomial of degree 3 and $F_{p^n}$ is finite , so the galois group of $K/F_{p^n}$  (where $K$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $F_{p^n}$)  is cyclic and $Gal(K/F_{p^n})$ can be $S_3$ or  $A_3$. as the galois group is cyclic hence the galois group is $A_3$ which implies $-4a^3-27b^2$(which is the discriminant of $f$) is a square in $F_{p^n}$.

is this correct?

Comment: Dear Jim, This looks good to me.  Regards,

Comment: +1 Jim. Care to copy/paste the *answer* part to an answer?

Comment: I wanted you to consider answering your own question, as it may happen that no one has anything to add. Your call, of course!